# Using selenium WebDriver to make an automaton for a site. However for some reason the xpath is underlined. Anyone the know the cause?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromium

Hey SO community once again im running into a small problem while trying to automate a daily questionnaire.

So I'm watching this [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pUUhvJvs-R4) tutorial and I know ones going to go through the hassle to check what the guy is doing for reference at approximately 5:50 he copies the `xpath` and pastes it on the side, however when I do it it gets underlined in red.
here's the what I did

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/name/Desktop/Selenium/chromedriver')

url = 'https://healthscreening.schools.nyc/?type=G'

driver.get(url)

//*[@id="guest_last_name"]

//*[@id="guest_email"]

//*[@id="btnDailyScreeningSubmit"]/button

driver.find_element_by_xpath('')...
```

The `/*[@id=""]` part is all underlined in red does anyone know the cause of the problem is? Thanks

Comment: Did you comment it out since in python ## is so and the compiler might be picking up on that.

Comment: No I didn’t comment anything out

Comment: Those lines need to be commented out since they will be flagged by the compiler for not being valid python.

Answer (score 0):

The code below

```
//*[@id="guest_last_name"]

//*[@id="guest_email"]

//*[@id="btnDailyScreeningSubmit"]/button
```

Is not valid Python code; this is why you have the error and the red underline.

If you want to find the element with that x-path you have to use

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id=\"guest_last_name\"]")
```

and so on